# How to write Null Properties when Serializing POCO class to JSON string?

Tags: .net, json.net

I have a Class as below

```
public class User
    {

        [JsonProperty("username")]
        string userName;
        public string Username {

            get { return userName + " Jack"; }
            set { userName = value; }
        } 

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("badges")]
        public List<Badge> Badges { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("accounts")]
        public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }


    public class Account
    {

        [JsonProperty("role")]
        public string Role = "Default";
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description = null;
        [JsonProperty("accessLevel")]
        public string AccessLevel = null;
    }

    public class Badge
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name = null;
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description;
        [JsonProperty("created")]
        public string Created;
        [JsonProperty("badge")]
        public string BadgeUrl = null;
    }
```

I am de-serializing a JSON to this class as below, note that in JSON the Account section is not passed

```
{
  "username": "mdeiters",
  "Username": "mdeiters Sathish",
  "location": "San Francisco",
  "endorsements": 120,
  "team": "14748",
  "badges": [
    {
      "name": "Charity",
      "description": "Fork and commit to someone's open source project in need",
      "created": "2013-06-14T22:40:45Z",
      "badge": "https://d3levm2kxut31z.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/charity-b7c8758441a70e8378d6332ec15ef292.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "KO Judge",
      "description": "Official Judge of the 2012 Node Knockout",
      "created": "2012-11-30T01:39:08Z",
      "badge": "https://d3levm2kxut31z.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/ko-judge-2012-4e9a536d23bf17b7401de8a6f6e28024.png"
    }
  ]
 }
```

After which i am Serializing this POCO class to JSON String

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(strInput);
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include });
```

But when i check my output string user it gives

```
"{\r\n  \"username\": \"mdeiters Sathish\",\r\n  \"Username\": \"mdeiters Sathish Sathish\",\r\n  \"name\": null,\r\n  \"location\": \"San Francisco\",\r\n  \"endorsements\": 120,\r\n  \"team\": \"14748\",\r\n  \"badges\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"name\": \"Charity\",\r\n      \"description\": \"Fork and commit to someone's open source project in need\",\r\n      \"created\": \"2013-06-14T22:40:45Z\",\r\n      \"badge\": \"https://d3levm2kxut31z.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/charity-b7c8758441a70e8378d6332ec15ef292.png\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"name\": \"KO Judge\",\r\n      \"description\": \"Official Judge of the 2012 Node Knockout\",\r\n      \"created\": \"2012-11-30T01:39:08Z\",\r\n      \"badge\": \"https://d3levm2kxut31z.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/ko-judge-2012-4e9a536d23bf17b7401de8a6f6e28024.png\"\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"accounts\": null\r\n}"
```

In which the Account is Null i want the accounts to be written as below

```
\"accounts\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"role\": null,\r\n      \"description\": null,\r\n      \"accessLevel\": null\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
```

Please help me in solving this

Comment: The `"accounts"` property is null because the JSON in `strInput` has no accounts, thus the `List<Account> Accounts` is never populated.  What else would you expect?

Comment: Also, what do you want if you just do `var user = new User();` ?  Should the array be allocated and populated with a default account?  Or should a default account only be allocated when reading from JSON?

Comment: That is the requirement for me, when the accounts is null, i want it to be populated with all the properties inside accounts as null. Check the format of JSON what i am excepting. I want account to be allocated when reading from JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one hand your JSON string does not have `accounts` property which means your `User` object will have `Accounts` property as `NULL` and on the other hand in your out put you want object of `Account` property to be `NULL` not property itself. So it can be achieve by two ways. 
1) You will need to have following json string as input.

```
{
    "username": "mdeiters",
    "Username": "mdeiters Sathish",
    "location": "San Francisco",
    "endorsements": 120,
    "team": "14748",
    "badges": [
        {
            "name": "Charity",
            "description": "Fork and commit to someone's open source project in need",
            "created": "2013-06-14T22:40:45Z",
            "badge": "https://d3levm2kxut31z.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/charity-b7c8758441a70e8378d6332ec15ef292.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "KO Judge",
            "description": "Official Judge of the 2012 Node Knockout",
            "created": "2012-11-30T01:39:08Z",
            "badge": "https://d3levm2kxut31z.cloudfront.net/assets/badges/ko-judge-2012-4e9a536d23bf17b7401de8a6f6e28024.png"
        }
    ],
    "accounts": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

)

Or
2) You will have to initialize your `accounts` property once you deserialize your object

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(strInput);
user.Accounts = new List<Account>();
user.Accounts.add(new Account());
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include });
```

Any of this should yield desired result.

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for, i used your option 2. Thanks Sameer!

Answer (score 0):

You want to serialize NULL value? if I find out your question correctly then you can take a look at JsonSerializerSettings class and inside this class take a look at NullValueHandling property and check if it can help you or not.

Comment: in this line: string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include }); change it to : string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include  }); http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm

Comment: by chaning this i am getting \"accounts\": null\r\n but not the properties inside the Accounts class